# Is there a GIT client for z/OS?

Tags: git, tfs, zos

We are looking for a solution to consolidate the version control of our code across a .net and z/OS platform. We are currently investigating the option of using our Team Foundation Server's GIT support to do this, but googling for z/OS and GIT doesn't lead to something interesting. Is there some way to use GIT on a z/OS platform?

Comment: Rocket Software has a port of Git to z/OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Release Notes for Git 1.8.2](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c490a6079021a3343ca5b042b37258858fdefbfc/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt) (March 2013) mention

> Initial ports to QNX and z/OS UNIX System Services have started.

So maybe now is a good time to try again...

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to build git on that platform, but, as [this thread shows](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Build-fixes-for-another-obscure-Unix-td7572980.html), there are compatibility fixes to do.

Comment: When I found the page earlier on I feared that git and z/OS is not a good match as the page is almost a year old and I haven't found reports about succesful & stabile builds

Comment: @LarsNielsen I agree. You might have to go and try build it, to see if those issues persist.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, z/OS supports the Single UNIX Specification, so you should be able to compile git and use it on z/OS.  The git community is generally supportive, so make sure to report any issues you run into: http://git-scm.com/community

Have you tried building Git on z/OS?